# i need a oracle query to Remove duplicate within a value

Tags: sql, csv, oracle11g, split

```
 FILM_ID    TITLE       
---------- ---------- 
    1       Frozen,Frozen         
    2       Frozen,High,Low,High 


 FILM_ID    TITLE       
---------- ---------- 
    1       Frozen
    2       Frozen,High,Low
```

If the value is `Frozen,Frozen` I need query to get only frozen as well as in a second value I should have `Frozen,High,Low`

Comment: You shouldn't be storing comma separated values in a single column in the first place. This is a really bad database design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
SELECT film_id, LISTAGG(title,',') WITHIN GROUP (Order BY title) TITLE
FROM 
(select distinct film_id, 
        regexp_substr(Title,'[^,]+', 1, level) as title
 from Table1
 connect by regexp_substr(Title, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
) t
GROUP BY film_id
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
FILM_ID |  TITLE
--------------------------
 1      |  Frozen
 2      |  Frozen,High,Low
```

Link To the demo:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/12377c/14

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option:

- TEST is your table
- INTER creates rows out of your comma separated values; DISTINCT is here to return only distinct values (as that's what you want)
- the final query aggregates them back

---

```
SQL> with test (film_id, title) as
  2    (select 1, 'Frozen,Frozen'        from dual union
  3     select 2, 'Frozen,High,Low,High' from dual
  4    ),
  5  inter as
  6    (select distinct film_id, regexp_substr(title, '[^,]+', 1, column_value) title
  7     from test,
  8          table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  9                              connect by level <= regexp_count(title, ',') + 1
 10                             ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 11    )
 12  select film_id, listagg(title, ',') within group (order by title) title
 13  from inter
 14  group by film_id;

   FILM_ID TITLE
---------- ------------------------------
         1 Frozen
         2 Frozen,High,Low
```